# nmcli: WIFI-HW vs WIFI, (and WWAN-HW vs WWAN)?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, gnu

In **nmcli** radio status, given by:

```
$ sudo nmcli radio all      # Show status of all radio network interfaces
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

Is   `-HW` for **H**ard**w**are?

Do these -HW status's report then say if the hardware is powered on, or plugged in?

And is the plain `WIFI` status, for if the software is enabled or not?

Answer (score 2):

-HW stands for Hardware. see also

```
  nmcli general
```

giving you a colourful status of the hardware etc..